# How does video players display video grater than native resolution of monitor?

Tags: x11, gstreamer, vlc, xorg, xbmc

I have a 1920x1080 resolution MP4 video file. It is encoded using H.264 video codec.

My monitor's native resolution is 1280x780. I am able to play this video file in vlc player or using totem player without any issue.

Can somebody explain me how video players display video files larger than the monitor's native resolution?

Answer (score 2):

Image scaling algorithms can be used at different levels: by video player itself, by operating system, even by monitor hardware. Simplest method of image scaling is "nearest-neighbor scaling", picking the nearest pixel colour. There are some advanced techniques, however, you can find them in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling).

Answer (score 0):

Stretching it down. That is, leaving some pixels out of the painting. The same as resizing down an image with a paint program.

Comment: Yes, although the actual 'shrinking' is most likely done by hardware in the video card (which is also capable of upscaling a video that is smaller than your screen).